# Are dual quaternions and 3D multivectors isomorphic?

Tags: geometry, 3d, quaternions, clifford-algebras

[Dual quaternions](https://cs.gmu.edu/~jmlien/teaching/cs451/uploads/Main/dual-quaternion.pdf) are popularly used as a representation of SE(3) in animation and robotics, with the second 'epsilon' quaternion used to encode translation.  This feels fairly natural, as the fact that rotation can influence position but position cannot influence rotation is built directly into the structure.

Nonetheless, it seems like the [3D multivectors](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4361175/#sec008title) of geometric/clifford algebra might be an even more natural fit, since the units associated with the vector and bivector components would actually match the geometric dimension of the quantities that they encode.  However, when multiplied these allow the odd elements from the two multivectors to combine and feed back into the even 'rotor' components.

Is there a simple mapping between these two algebras, perhaps achieved by pre-multiplying the odd elements by a nilpotent multivector (maybe |1 + e0^e1^e2|), or do these two algebras fundamentally have different behavior?

Comment: $\Bbb{H} $ is the real subalgebra $ \Bbb{R}^* SU_2(\Bbb{C}) \cup \{0\}$ of $M_2(\Bbb{C})$ and dual quaternions are $\Bbb{H}[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)= \Bbb{H}+\epsilon  \Bbb{H}$ where the second $\Bbb{H}$ can be seen as $\Bbb{R}^4$ onto which the first $\Bbb{H}$ acts both on the left and the right. The group isomorphism $\Bbb{H}^* \to SO_3(\Bbb{R})$ is not linear so quaternions are not quite (scaled) rotations.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that quaternions are effectively the square roots of scaled rotations, since you generally apply a quaternion on the left of a vector and then apply its conjugate on the right in order to rotate it?

Comment: According to your link, $\overline{(e_0\wedge e_1\wedge e_2)}=e_0\wedge e_1\wedge e_2$, and that multivector would be $$\mid1+e_0\wedge e_1\wedge e_2\mid=\sqrt{(1+e_0\wedge e_1\wedge e_2)^2}=\pm(1+e_0\wedge e_1\wedge e_2).$$ Is this what you meant? And is $e_0\!^2=+1$ or $-1$?

Comment: I think you'd be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_geometric_algebra , http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/html/ComputationalGeometry.html . The dual quaternions are isomorphic to a Clifford subalgebra over a 5-dimensional space (which contains 3D Euclidean space as a curved submanifold).

Comment: Absolutely!  I'd come across it before at https://crypto.stanford.edu/~blynn/haskell/cga.html, but in implementing it as a data structure it wasn't totally clear quite how much would be gained by going to a 32 element multivector given what dual quaternions could do with 8 components.  A lot of references like to stick to even sub-algebras and I was hoping to find more structure to exploit in the odd components.

Comment: Regarding my suggested nilpotent vector, I was conjecturing normalizing the sum of the scalar and the 3D pseudo-scalar which squares to -1, as an attempt to find a value to replace the role of the epsilon that squares to zero in the dual quaternions (as much as normalization makes sense for a nilpotent vector).  Conformal GA introduces two additional dimensions squaring to opposite signs in order to effectively use their combination as an orthogonal epsilon, which intuitively felt... excessive?

Comment: I agree that using 2 extra dimensions feels excessive. But the Euclidean submanifold is contained in a 4D affine subspace; almost all of the relevant algebra is generated by $e_1,e_2,e_3,n_\infty$, and the position vectors are just displaced by a constant $n_o$. So the multivectors essentially have 16 components. The even subalgebra encodes rotations and translations. The odd subalgebra encodes reflections (and glide reflections and roto-reflections).

Comment: @Jason The dual quaternions are also already the Clifford algebra of a form of signature $(-1,-1,0)$, too.  I lack intuition for the even subalterns models.

Comment: @mr_e_man autocorrect mangled “even subalgebras”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> are dual quaternions and 3D multivectors isomorphic?

Not as rings: the first is isomorphic to $\mathbb H[X]/(X^2)$ and the second is isomorphic to $M_2(\mathbb C)$.  The first one has a nonzero central nilpotent element and the second does not.

As $\mathbb R$ vector spaces, yes, because any two $8$-dimensional real vector spaces are isomorphic.

> Would it be fair to say that quaternions are effectively the square roots of scaled rotations?

No, because it suggests “$q^2=kR$ for some rotation $R$ and scalar $k$ is a rotation” which seems meaningless to me.  The fact is that *all nonzero quaternions effect rotations using the conjugation action.* The ones effecting the same rotation differ by a scalar.

Answer (score 2):

$1+e_0e_1e_2$ isn't nilpotent. If your basis vectors square to $-1$ then the algebra is isomorphic to $\mathbb H\oplus\mathbb H$ and there are no nilpotents. If they square to $+1$ then the algebra is isomorphic to $M_2(\mathbb C)$ and there are nilpotents (such as $e_0+e_0e_1$), but there isn't enough room to encode a translation and it certainly isn't natural.

As someone else mentioned, you can introduce an extra dimension with metric signature $0$ to get an algebra isomorphic to the dual quaternions. But they used the full algebra of signature $-{-}0$, which technically is isomorphic but doesn't make physical sense and (as they observed) doesn't have a natural action on vectors. You should instead use signature $-{--}0$ or $+{++}0$ and the even part of the algebra, if you do this. Writing the basis as $\{\hat x,\hat y,\hat z,\hat\epsilon\}$, your general even element can be written $q_1 + \hat x\hat y\hat z\hat\epsilon\,q_2$, where $q_i = a_i \pm (b_i\hat y\hat z + c_i\hat z\hat x + d_i\hat x\hat y)$. (The $\pm$ depends on your signature, and should be chosen to reproduce the standard quaternion convention that $ijk=-1$.)

You can also introduce two new coordinates $\hat t$ and $\hat w$ with $\hat t^2=-\hat w^2$ and only consider terms proportional to $\hat t+\hat w$, but that seems unnecessarily complicated.

Here's a different way of approaching the problem that is perhaps more elegant.

Euclidean 3-space sits somewhat uncomfortably between elliptical and hyperbolic 3-space, both of which have nicer symmetry groups ($O(4)$ and $O(3,1)$ respectively). Given that Euclidean space is an approximation anyway, you may as well pick an approximation that has a nicer symmetry group. For example, you could pick an elliptical space with a curvature radius equal to $R_\text{earth}$. This is not precisely correct, especially in the up-down direction, but neither is x=north-south, y=east-west, z=up-down, and distance=$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. You can represent arbitrary continuous transformations of the elliptical space by elements of the even Clifford algebra of $\mathbb R^4$.

If you implement this, you'll probably run into precision problems because the distances you'll be dealing with will be small compared to $R_\text{earth}$. You'll end up representing positions and transformations as separate large and small parts, scaled by a fixed ratio $\epsilon \sim 1/R_\text{earth}$ in convenient units, and neglecting terms of order $\epsilon^2$. In other words, you'll end up with the dual quaternions again. But this is arguably a nicer way of thinking about them.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't what you're looking for, but the dual quaternions are isomorphic to a 3D Clifford algebra with a degenerate quadratic form, defined by

$$(xe_1+ye_2+ze_3)^2=-x^2-y^2.$$

$$i=e_1,\quad j=e_2,\quad k=e_1e_2,\quad \varepsilon=e_1e_2e_3$$

The problem here is that, if we're applying this to 3D rigid motions, the "vectors" do not correspond to directions in physical space. So this is no better than the usual "abstract" definition in terms of the mutiplicative relations of $i,j,k,\varepsilon$.

Actually, if we rename $e_3=n_\infty$, then this is clearly related to the conformal geometric algebra of *two-dimensional* space.

Comment: I continued digging after asking the question, and encountered this paper comparing PGA = Cl(3,0,1) and CGA = Cl(4,1): https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.6502.pdf.

It still seems kind of crazy to me that the only real use cases I've encountered for the odd elements of Cl(3) are in implementing reflections and inversions!  I guess it kind of makes sense that translations would map to 'infinitesimal rotations', but it is still kind of surprising that in some sense rotation is a more fundamental operation.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'd been wondering about using a degenerate metric to model $\mathbb E^2$. The $(1,0,2)$ metric is too degenerate; it only does translations, not rotations. $(2,0,1)$ appears to have a cylinder as its "unit sphere", which is clearly not an acceptable model of the plane. But that cylinder is actually the space of _lines_, not points, in the Euclidean plane! I'd known about duality before, but never thought of applying it in this way.